# a monotonic sequence $\{x_n\}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ is convergent iff the sequence $\{(x_n)^2\}$ is convergent

Tags: real-analysis

a monotonic sequence $\{x_n\}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ is convergent iff the sequence $\{(x_n)^2\}$ is convergent.

Forward Implications is easy, nothing to worry about that. I am confused about backward implication For backward Implication my attempt.

Attempt(Please check if this reasoning is True)

Case 1:- 
 $\{x_n\}$ is Increasing.
We have two possibilities further.

Either all  $x_n<0$ or  $x_n >0$ for n>N, where N is some natural number.

When  all  $x_n<0$ , we have it bounded above by 0. Hence its convergent.

Now if   $x_n >0$ for n>N, where N is some natural number.  Then because  $\{(x_n)^2\}$ is convergent implies $(\{x_n)^2\}$ is bounded above. Hence 
$\{x_n\}$ is also bounded above. Hence $\{x_n\}$ is convergent.

Simmilar for when $\{x_n\}$ is decreasing.

If its not correct, Tell me the solution

Comment: This almost works. You need to prove that $x_n$ is bounded in the case that $x_n>0$ eventually. You say it, but don’t prove it.

Comment: This argument is perfect.